# Transactional Emails Issue - Load Default Template list shows blank

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I am working with Magento version 1.6.1.0 . I just went on to create a Transactional Email but the page after 'Add New Template' just shows Load Default Template drop down list which is empty.

I checked my app/locale/en_US/template/email/ and I can see a whole list of default email templates. But I dont see them listed under 'Load default Template'. Also ideally there should be other fields on that page like 'Template Name, locale, Template Content' etc in order to create a new template.

But its has got none of them but just this 'Load default Template' drop down,  that too empty. Also i don't know if there is any other files associated to show this section in the core and where should I start looking to solve this problem.

Any input is appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Couple of things to do: 1. Check permissions on the email directory, 2. Check your logs and see if there are any errors

Comment: Sorry for delay in reply. I have checked the permissions and they all seem fine. Also there is nothing I can find out in the log too. Is there anything else I can do? Any folder which displays the Transactional Email Templates and loads default ones form the back end that I can delete and reload? Anything at all

Comment: Usually, if the page stops rendering like it sounds it has, you will have an error in the apache error log, have you checked this log?

Comment: Where can I look for apache error log because the only log I see is system.log? Is that the one?

Comment: depending on the system it's either under /var/log/httpd or /var/log/apache2. Note that this is not the same var/log as the magento one, but from the root directory on the system

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply again. Seems like I never get a notification when a comment is posted in this thread, or maybe I just miss it. My bad!.Apologies. I checked the root directory of my system and never found any var folder at all. It just has .cpanel, .htpasswds, public_ftp, public_html, tmp and www folders.

Comment: Ok, sounds like you are on a shared host? The only other thing I can think to do is find the code that loads the templates and sprinkle logging through it, to help find where it's stopping

Comment: I tried that but I am not too sure If I have done it correctly. As far as I can remember I tried altering the app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Email/Template code. I also deleted and reloaded that folder but nothing seem to get it work. Also the same thing happened in one of my other sites, I tried creating a transactional email template in my code and the page broke down. I reverted back the changes and it was running fine again. However nothing seem to get my this site's page running up again.

Comment: Thanks for your help @CCBlackburn, checked the apache error log and it was indeed because of a missing Helper class from another unrelated module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just had exactly the same issue. Looking at the comments above, yes it is system.log.

It turned out to be a Module for sending review notifications, the module was disabled in the backend but needed to be manually set to false in app/etc/modules for me to be able to create new email templates.

I suppose the moral of my story is don't assume it's something to do with the core email templates/system, it could easily be a conflict with something which seems totally unrelated. The error log will tell you what!

Comment: Magento!! why u no make sense?? My email list suddenly stopped populating - the log dumped out a random missing helper class. But I'm not using a helper in that module?! What? - Magento requires a helper/data.php for modules (even empty...) Did not know this. And... its trashing my email list of all things? Seriously... wtf

Comment: @Bosworth99 agree, that doesn't make sense at all, just encountered this same problem and it was because of another module that doesn't have Helper class, this module is totally not related to transactional emails module.